# How to add title to the plot of shap.plots.force with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, shap

I want to add some modifications to my force plot (created by `shap.plots.force`) using Matplotlib, e.g. adding title, using tight layout etc. However, I tried to add title and the title doesn't show up. Any ideas why and how can I add the title using Matplotlib?

```
import numpy as np
import shap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myBaseline=1.5
shap_values_0 = np.array([-1, -4, 3])
test_point_0 = np.array([11, 12, 13])
features_names = ['a1','a2','a3']

shap.plots.force(myBaseline,shap_values_0,test_point_0,features_names,matplotlib = 1)
plt.suptitle("This is my title")    # It doesn't show up, why?
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last lines in `force_plot` [are](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/plots/_force_matplotlib.py#L407):

```
if show:
    plt.show()
else:
    return plt.gcf()
```

so, if you set `show = False` you can get prepared SHAP plot as `figure` object and customize it to your needs as usual:

```
import shap

myBaseline = 1.5
shap_values_0 = np.array([-1, -4, 3])
test_point_0 = np.array([11, 12, 13])
features_names = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]

shap.plots.force(
    myBaseline, shap_values_0, test_point_0, features_names, matplotlib=True, show=False
)
plt.title("This is my title", y=1.75)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Well shouldn't `shap.plots.force` when called return a matplotlib figure object? It returns `None`.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add `show=0` at `shap.plots.force`, i.e.

```
shap.plots.force(myBaseline,shap_values_0,test_point_0,features_names,matplotlib = 1, show=0)
```

I have no idea why it works, but it does.

[image]

Comment: Good job; but admittedly it does not look much of a title, does it?

Comment: Regarding the formatting, perhaps we can use `plt.title("This is my title")` instead of `plt.suptitle("This is my title")`? It looks a little bit better (but not much).